# Laravel FileBag is limited to 20 files

Tags: laravel, upload, react-dropzone

I can not find any source about file bag's file amount limits

I have route in my application where i let user upload bunch of photos.No matter how much space the files occupying the max amount is 20 photos;

**Request Headers**

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 188603
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Cookie: refreshToken=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%3D; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InVsbVl0U29HTFI4YUxKOG0zbEVBNEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiejEzeEFwZzdIWU91UjVoMGZnelhmNVhBcVFUV1FjK2FNc2lKSytsbklwOUFWSms4NnViOHVxQU9EQ0g0MlIrZUI0N0pEc3lZUVA4UENTMlZkMFZnU3c9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjM4MDRlN2M1YTAwMmYwZjkzZmU0ZjUzM2UwM2EyOTcxOTZkNDMwY2Y5NDU5OWViYjdhNzY4MDA1YjNhMDI3YzEifQ%3D%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IlJ4QUlDTnJmWEJXdFR6QTJyM1BmWkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTTAwajhveFdURWYwcFBMZjhJZ1RWWlZrR3ZQM0tCNWhUR3JjOXczckZUQnlVSUgxMWR6cktRbVpaQ2F0aklGbmNQQTRQQ2wrNGZLZTR5VG5ydGxUelE9PSIsIm1hYyI6Ijg1ZWZkYmIxZGUyNmM2ZmUyYjBhZmNiYjExYjc5MDE2YzU1YzFhODk5ZDNlYzM3NDc0MzM1ZTQ4YjA5OTUyYTYifQ%3D%3D
Host: legenda-jaroslaw.test
Origin: http://legenda-jaroslaw.test
Referer: http://legenda-jaroslaw.test/galeria/albumy/6
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-TOKEN: 3wy03HBK8KgaEUV9SDdKF1r58dP64EZO5pRHFwBD
X-XSRF-TOKEN: eyJpdiI6InVsbVl0U29HTFI4YUxKOG0zbEVBNEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiejEzeEFwZzdIWU91UjVoMGZnelhmNVhBcVFUV1FjK2FNc2lKSytsbklwOUFWSms4NnViOHVxQU9EQ0g0MlIrZUI0N0pEc3lZUVA4UENTMlZkMFZnU3c9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjM4MDRlN2M1YTAwMmYwZjkzZmU0ZjUzM2UwM2EyOTcxOTZkNDMwY2Y5NDU5OWViYjdhNzY4MDA1YjNhMDI3YzEifQ==
```

**Request Payload**

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photos"

[{"name":"images - Kopia.jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_0"},{"name":"images (1) - Kopia.jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_1"},{"name":"images (1).jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_2"},{"name":"images (2) - Kopia.jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_3"},{"name":"images (2).jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_4"},{"name":"images.jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_5"},{"name":"pobrane - Kopia.jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_6"},{"name":"pobrane (1) - Kopia.jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_7"},{"name":"pobrane (1).jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_8"},{"name":"pobrane (2) - Kopia.jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_9"},{"name":"pobrane (2).jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_10"},{"name":"pobrane (3) - Kopia.jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_11"},{"name":"pobrane (3).jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_12"},{"name":"pobrane (4) - Kopia.jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_13"},{"name":"pobrane (4).jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_14"},{"name":"pobrane (5) - Kopia.jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_15"},{"name":"pobrane (5).jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_16"},{"name":"pobrane (6) - Kopia.jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_17"},{"name":"pobrane (6).jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_18"},{"name":"pobrane (7) - Kopia.jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_19"},{"name":"pobrane (7).jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_20"},{"name":"pobrane (8) - Kopia.jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_21"},{"name":"pobrane (8).jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_22"},{"name":"pobrane.jpg","description":"none","imageFileId":"photo_23"}]
------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="albumId"

6
------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_0"; filename="images - Kopia.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_1"; filename="images (1) - Kopia.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_2"; filename="images (1).jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_3"; filename="images (2) - Kopia.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_4"; filename="images (2).jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_5"; filename="images.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_6"; filename="pobrane - Kopia.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_7"; filename="pobrane (1) - Kopia.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_8"; filename="pobrane (1).jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_9"; filename="pobrane (2) - Kopia.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_10"; filename="pobrane (2).jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_11"; filename="pobrane (3) - Kopia.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_12"; filename="pobrane (3).jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_13"; filename="pobrane (4) - Kopia.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_14"; filename="pobrane (4).jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_15"; filename="pobrane (5) - Kopia.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_16"; filename="pobrane (5).jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_17"; filename="pobrane (6) - Kopia.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_18"; filename="pobrane (6).jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_19"; filename="pobrane (7) - Kopia.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_20"; filename="pobrane (7).jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_21"; filename="pobrane (8) - Kopia.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_22"; filename="pobrane (8).jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhD60cXso2pz2N59Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo_23"; filename="pobrane.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

**Controller Method**

```
   public function store(Request $request, GalleryService $galleryService)
    {
        $photos = json_decode($request->input('photos'));
        $photoFiles = $request->file();
        dd($request->file());
        $albumId = $request->input('albumId');
        return response()->json($galleryService->addPhotos($photos, $photoFiles, $albumId));
}
```

This is what i get when i inspect the fileBag

```
array:20 [
  "photo_0" => UploadedFile {#247
    -test: false
    -originalName: "images - Kopia.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 9335
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpf2zQAa"
    basename: "phpf2zQAa"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpf2zQAa"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpf2zQAa"
    aTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    mTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    cTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    inode: 3280671
    size: 9335
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo_1" => UploadedFile {#248
    -test: false
    -originalName: "images (1) - Kopia.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 3383
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpkQAabn"
    basename: "phpkQAabn"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpkQAabn"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpkQAabn"
    aTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    mTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    cTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    inode: 3282134
    size: 3383
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo_2" => UploadedFile {#249
    -test: false
    -originalName: "images (1).jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 3383
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpudQuLz"
    basename: "phpudQuLz"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpudQuLz"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpudQuLz"
    aTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    mTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    cTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    inode: 3282142
    size: 3383
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo_3" => UploadedFile {#250
    -test: false
    -originalName: "images (2) - Kopia.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 6889
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpgmhPlM"
    basename: "phpgmhPlM"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpgmhPlM"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpgmhPlM"
    aTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    mTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    cTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    inode: 3282143
    size: 6889
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo_4" => UploadedFile {#251
    -test: false
    -originalName: "images (2).jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 6889
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpgZY9VY"
    basename: "phpgZY9VY"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpgZY9VY"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpgZY9VY"
    aTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    mTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    cTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    inode: 3282144
    size: 6889
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo_5" => UploadedFile {#252
    -test: false
    -originalName: "images.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 9335
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpebWuwb"
    basename: "phpebWuwb"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpebWuwb"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpebWuwb"
    aTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    mTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    cTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    inode: 3282145
    size: 9335
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo_6" => UploadedFile {#253
    -test: false
    -originalName: "pobrane - Kopia.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 8910
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpXRbQ6n"
    basename: "phpXRbQ6n"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpXRbQ6n"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpXRbQ6n"
    aTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    mTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    cTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    inode: 3282146
    size: 8910
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo_7" => UploadedFile {#254
    -test: false
    -originalName: "pobrane (1) - Kopia.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 9883
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "php2OJbHA"
    basename: "php2OJbHA"
    pathname: "/tmp/php2OJbHA"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/php2OJbHA"
    aTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    mTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    cTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    inode: 3282147
    size: 9883
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo_8" => UploadedFile {#255
    -test: false
    -originalName: "pobrane (1).jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 9883
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "php91zxhN"
    basename: "php91zxhN"
    pathname: "/tmp/php91zxhN"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/php91zxhN"
    aTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    mTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    cTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    inode: 3282148
    size: 9883
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo_9" => UploadedFile {#256
    -test: false
    -originalName: "pobrane (2) - Kopia.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 6352
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpfdITRZ"
    basename: "phpfdITRZ"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpfdITRZ"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpfdITRZ"
    aTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    mTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    cTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    inode: 3282149
    size: 6352
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo_10" => UploadedFile {#257
    -test: false
    -originalName: "pobrane (2).jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 6352
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpyA5fsc"
    basename: "phpyA5fsc"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpyA5fsc"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpyA5fsc"
    aTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    mTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    cTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    inode: 3282150
    size: 6352
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo_11" => UploadedFile {#258
    -test: false
    -originalName: "pobrane (3) - Kopia.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 7811
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phptbGC2o"
    basename: "phptbGC2o"
    pathname: "/tmp/phptbGC2o"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phptbGC2o"
    aTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    mTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    cTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    inode: 3282151
    size: 7811
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo_12" => UploadedFile {#259
    -test: false
    -originalName: "pobrane (3).jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 7811
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpK5I0CB"
    basename: "phpK5I0CB"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpK5I0CB"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpK5I0CB"
    aTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    mTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    cTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    inode: 3282152
    size: 7811
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo_13" => UploadedFile {#260
    -test: false
    -originalName: "pobrane (4) - Kopia.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 7974
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpIc4odO"
    basename: "phpIc4odO"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpIc4odO"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpIc4odO"
    aTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    mTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    cTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    inode: 3282153
    size: 7974
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo_14" => UploadedFile {#261
    -test: false
    -originalName: "pobrane (4).jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 7974
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpZdFNN0"
    basename: "phpZdFNN0"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpZdFNN0"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpZdFNN0"
    aTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    mTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    cTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    inode: 3282154
    size: 7974
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo_15" => UploadedFile {#262
    -test: false
    -originalName: "pobrane (5) - Kopia.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 6768
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "php0jvcod"
    basename: "php0jvcod"
    pathname: "/tmp/php0jvcod"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/php0jvcod"
    aTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    mTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    cTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    inode: 3282155
    size: 6768
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo_16" => UploadedFile {#263
    -test: false
    -originalName: "pobrane (5).jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 6768
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpcKBBYp"
    basename: "phpcKBBYp"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpcKBBYp"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpcKBBYp"
    aTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    mTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    cTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    inode: 3282156
    size: 6768
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo_17" => UploadedFile {#264
    -test: false
    -originalName: "pobrane (6) - Kopia.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 6544
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpTYX0yC"
    basename: "phpTYX0yC"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpTYX0yC"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpTYX0yC"
    aTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    mTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    cTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    inode: 3282157
    size: 6544
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo_18" => UploadedFile {#265
    -test: false
    -originalName: "pobrane (6).jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 6544
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phptwAq9O"
    basename: "phptwAq9O"
    pathname: "/tmp/phptwAq9O"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phptwAq9O"
    aTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    mTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    cTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    inode: 3282158
    size: 6544
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  "photo_19" => UploadedFile {#266
    -test: false
    -originalName: "pobrane (7) - Kopia.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 9634
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpkWSQJ1"
    basename: "phpkWSQJ1"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpkWSQJ1"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpkWSQJ1"
    aTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    mTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    cTime: 2018-05-10 14:50:54
    inode: 3282159
    size: 9634
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
]
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: No, i can only see those 20.

Comment: You need to set the `max_file_uploads` PHP setting to a higher value.

Comment: Change `max_file_uploads = 100` in your php.ini